# How do I copy a file from my AWS EC2 Ubuntu linux instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-s3

I have a linux ubuntu instance and a S3 bucket
I did

```
sudo apt-get install s3cmd
```

then tried

```
s3cmd put datafile.xml s3://jthink/datafile.xml
```

where jthink is my bucket name

but it says

```
ERROR: /home/ubuntu/.s3cfg: No such file or directory
ERROR: Configuration file not available.
ERROR: Consider using --configure parameter to create one
```

so i ran

```
s3 --configure
```

and it asks for access keys, secret keys ectera I cannot find them, when I look at my S3 bucket in Amazon Web Console there seems to be no such thing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Access Key and Secret Key credentials are required for AWS API access and are used by many tools. Using the web management console you can find and create these credentials using the "Security Credentials" screen under your name on the top right.

But as your root account can not be restricted, it is very recommended that, when using third-party software, you create an IAM user with restricted privileges and/or different credentials. You can learn how to do that here: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/Using_SettingUpUser.html

Comment: Is this the .pem file i used to enable ssh access to my instance from my local machine ?

Comment: See this: http://www.cloudberrylab.com/blog/how-to-find-your-aws-access-key-id-and-secret-access-key-and-register-with-cloudberry-s3-explorer/

Comment: sorry I don't get it, is this is different to the keypair file that I use for ssh access to my EC2 instances, I have an AccessCode from back in 2006 but Ive only actively started using AWS recently and every time I create a a new instance I select to use my existing keypair.

Comment: Yes, it is different. The keypair is for EC2 instance authentication and the AccessKey / SecretKey are credentials for API calls that you need to provide to s3cmd. You can also use AWS CLI tools instead of s3cmd, here you can find the setup guide for that: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-chap-welcome.html